# QEMU multiple instances/ headless

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, qemu, device-emulation

I'm looking for a way to automate high load tests on Android apps. That means we need many virtual android devices that can be automated. QEMU came to my mind as it provides a free & open-source emulation software to emulate android devices.

- Is it possible to run multiple virtual android devices using QEMU on
  one server (otherwise, we would need a server for each virtual device).
- Is it also possible to run QEMU on a headless Linux? The best would
  be if the virtual android device can be accessed through a
  Browser-based GUI over the network to control it (embedded in a browser, like here https://www.genymotion.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/BROWSER-vd-cloud.gif)
- What would you recommend to me? I've already heard of Genymotion,
  which is made for that, but since we need high scalability, it would
  be way too expensive due to their license system.

Thank you!